# Best way to handle error from Write call in Go http handler

Tags: http, go, io, handler

What is best way to handle `Write` error in http handler.

```golang
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  n, err := w.Write([]byte("hi"))
  // how should we handle this error?
}
```

I suppose I can take n and try to Write again with remainder of bytes.

Comment: It is common practice  to ignore the error.

Comment: @ThunderCat I am aware. My question was how to handle this error if i dont want to ignore

Comment: You can log it, return an http server error, or ignore it. What's "best" is up to you.

Comment: @JimB I think the question is whether it is possible to retry the `Write()` call if it errors out (e.g. with a temporary network error).

Comment: @johlo: there's unlikely to be temporary errors at that point. There's typically a lot of layers buffering the caller from actual network connection. You're more likely to see things like `ErrContentLength`, `ErrBodyNotAllowed`, `ErrHijacked`, etc.

Comment: @JimB in typical case where write fails, would client receive 200 with partial data? In typical case, would it even be possible to return 5xx?

Comment: Good point, trying to return a server error probably isn’t feasible in most cases, or worth the effort even when it is.

Comment: The best you can do is log the error.  Errors at the network layer are usually because data cannot be sent to the peer.  There's no recovery from that.  The errors indicating a programmer error (ErrHijacked, ErrContentLength, ...) require a code fix.

Comment: "would it even be possible to return 5xx" no. Once `Write` has been called, it is too late to issue new status or headers using `WriteHeader`, due to the nature of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

At this point you will only see two types of errors:

- network errors, (*e.g.* if the client goes away while you are trying to send data), or
- errors caused by bugs in your server (*e.g.* if you manually set `Content-Length` and then try to write more data than you claimed, you will get `ErrContentLength`).

You can look at the implementation of the `response` class in [net/http/server.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go), to get an idea of errors you may see from the default `ResponseWriter`.
How to handle these errors?

- For errors like `ErrContentLength`, which indicate bugs in the server, it seems reasonable to log these, because the error messages may help to fix the server.
- To me it would seem reasonable to simply ignore network errors, but of course these could also be logged, if needed.
- One of the first things `Write()` does, is to make sure the headers are sent.  Thus, by the time you see an error code returned by `Write()`, it will be too late to attempt to change the HTTP status code.  Given this, it seems not worth trying (and probably is impossible) to notify the client that something went wrong.